How to Query SOAR Database to Extract Playbook Execution Time?
I am working with IBM SOAR (formerly Resilient) and I am trying to extract specific information regarding the execution of playbooks. Specifically, I want to retrieve the completion time of a playbook (e.g., "Send Email") as part of my workflow.
Here is the scenario:
I have a playbook running on SOAR, and at the end of the playbook, I need to query for the exact timestamp when the playbook finished executing.
Ideally, I would like to achieve this through a direct query to the SOAR database or using a REST API, but I’m unsure how to approach this.
What I’ve Tried:
Using the REST API:
I have looked at the incident and workflow-related endpoints, but I couldn’t find clear documentation on how to retrieve workflow execution logs or timestamps for specific playbooks.
If there's a specific endpoint or payload format I should use, I would appreciate guidance.
Direct Database Query:
I understand SOAR uses PostgreSQL for its backend, but I haven’t found detailed information on where playbook execution details (like timestamps) are stored in the database schema.
I have administrative access but need assistance identifying the relevant tables or fields.
What I Need:
A method (via API or database) to extract the end time of a specific playbook's execution.
If possible, an example query or script that shows how to retrieve this information.
Any advice, best practices, or references to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated.
